# How to pass integer value from parent prop to child prop in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

Basically I am working on a dice game where I have a class for Number of sides and another class for Number of dices. I want to get values from both classes and pass them to a child class where I will multiply both together to get `maxScore`. All classes are in same file

However, I get `NaN` as a result. I feel like I am not passing values correctly. All classes are in same file. I am new to React so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your `Child` component is never receiving both the props it needs, you are only ever giving it one or the other.

Comment: You are only passing one prop to each child component, why do you expect them both to exist in the same child?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both cases you are missing out one of the `props` values. So the component tries to multiply `undefined` with a number and that's why you are getting `NaN`.

Think about the following:

```js
console.log(6 * undefined);
console.log(undefined * 2);
```

As a solution you need to provide both values for `<Child>` component. Try the following:

```
<Child noOfSides={this.state.mystate} noOfDice={1} />

{/* or */}

<Child noOfDice={this.state.mystate} noOfSides={1}/>
```

I hope this explains!

Comment: Exactly. Components are **instances** of the classes. Each time you say `<Child />`, you're creating a new component instance. Instances can't share values from other instances, that doesn't make sense.